# Как сделать выпадающие блоки с описанием?

Tags: javascript, html, css, list

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open_card").click(function() {
    var id_card = $(this).data('id-card');
    $(".card_" + id_card + "").toggleClass("show_block");
    console.log(id_card);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Кнопки */

.rose_cards ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rose_cards li {
  width: 260px;
  height: 70px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rose_cards li:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px lightgreen;
  ;
}


/* Блоки с информацией */

.descriptions {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 135px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 195px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 130px;
  left: 28px;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.show_block {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Кнопки -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
      <div class="rose_cards">
        <ul>
          <li class="open_card_1" data-id-card="1">Блок 1</li>
          <li class="open_card_2" data-id-card="2">Блок 2</li>
          <li class="open_card_3" data-id-card="3">Блок 3</li>
          <li class="open_card_4" data-id-card="4">Блок 4</li>
          <li class="open_card_5" data-id-card="5">Блок 5</li>
          <li class="open_card_6" data-id-card="6">Блок 6</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Блоки с информацией -->
  <div class="descriptions">
    <!--       1-й блок        -->
    <div class="wrap card_1"></div>
    <!--       2-й блок           -->
    <div class="wrap card_2"></div>
    <!--      3-й блок           -->
    <div class="wrap card_3"></div>
    <!--      4-й блок     -->
    <div class="wrap card_4"></div>
    <!--   5-й блок    -->
    <div class="wrap card_5"></div>
    <!--     6-й блок    -->
    <div class="wrap card_6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сделал в общем то сам. Но мне кажется, что не правильно. Много кода и есть смещение блоков относительно кнопок. Хотелось бы что-бы каждый блок выпадал точно из под своей кнопки.

Если это возможно помогите оформить мою идею более правильно, элегантно.

Comment: не существует в природе `align-item`, есть `align-items` и если  элемент не `display:flex;`, в этом правилен нет смысла

Comment: вопрос не об этом. код вытащен из разработки сайта. что то подчистил , что то пропустил.

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю, что вопрос не об этом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сократить код JS можно таким путем! Можно код сократить до одного условия сделав дополнительный параметр data к кнопкам, `<li class="open_card" data-id-card="1"><img src="images/m1.svg" alt="">Блок 1</li>`

```
 $(".open_card").click(function() {
    var id_card = $(this).data('id-card');
    $(".card_"+id_card+"").toggleClass("show_block");

  });
```

Ну и все!

Comment: data-id-card="1" Прямо так писать? Или тут опечатка? Может data = 'id-card';?
Усомнился потому что в скрипте написано так data('id-card');

Comment: не получается что то

Comment: @vvv7220 как я написал должно работать

Comment: Я вставил сюда исправленный код. Посмотри пожалуйста, я правильно сделал? Не работает.

Comment: Все разобрался. Там повнимательней посмотрел контактенацию. Спасибо!!! Ты гений!

Comment: @vvv7220 да не за что! =) не забудь поставить галочку у ответам =)